How to handle browser popup message with selenium?

How can I capture the "do you want to open facetime" message that pops up when I click on a link for a phone call with selenium chrome web driver?
operating system Macos
programming language C#
technology selenium

I tried sending the Escape character with the Actions class but it failed. Clicking the cancel button when the exact message I want appears.


Browser alerts needs to be handled via IAlert with Dismiss() or Accept() methods.
Sending keys like Escape via Actions won't work.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());

IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Dismiss();



Handling system-level pop-ups like the "Do you want to open
FaceTime?" alert in macOS using Selenium can be tricky, as these
pop-ups are not part of the browser's DOM and Selenium cannot
interact with them directly.

Use AutoIt (or similar tool) AutoIt is a scripting language designed
for automating the Windows GUI. Unfortunately, it doesn't work
natively on macOS. However, you can use a similar tool called
AppleScript to handle macOS pop-ups.


